# how could my viber messagelog dissapear?

Tags: samsung, viber-messenger

i was chatting on viber and then left for a couple of hours and when i were going to write a message again i saw that all of my previous messages had been deleted except for two of the latest ones. I havent updated or anything, what happend? can it update by itself and deleting messages?

Answer (score 0):

There is no situation in which Viber messages spontaneously delete themselves. Viber does not update without your permission - and updating does not delete messages.

If this occurred on Viber for Desktop, please ensure that the computer that you use is a private computer and no one but you can access it. Additionally, you might consider placing a screen lock on your phone so that your applications are better protected.

Comment: I think I just experienced such a situation. My mum got sick of her (Android) phone malfunctioning and bought a new one - it was then my job to resurrect as much data as I could from the old one. Would any of the following have caused Viber to delete its message history: 1. Mobile service (and number) being moved to a new phone with a new SIM, 2. Trying to run Viber with SIM removed, 3. Clearing phone's "Contacts Storage" data which was almost certainly corrupt (People (contacts app) and Viber wouldn't run until I did so), or 4. see next comment, the character limit's almost reached.

Comment: 4. When I finally got Viber to run, it asked me what my number was. I picked our country from the list and entered my mum's number, which ended up in "international form" (+61 4xxx... instead of "local form" 04xxx...), and Viber sent an activation code to said number. Does this mean it considers it now has a new account on the phone that's different from the old one (I don't know whether the number was originally in local form) and therefore created a new message history and/or deleted the old one? Is there any way to retrieve the message history as it was before all this? Viber version: 2.3.5